# XML Parser get specific atrributes by comparing its values

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have XML file content as shown below.

```
<FileIndex>
<Document SEQUENCE="0" FILENAME="A.xml"  />
<Document SEQUENCE="1" FILENAME="B.htm"  />
<Document SEQUENCE="2" FILENAME="C.htm"  />
<Document SEQUENCE="3" FILENAME="D.htm"  />
```

I want to get the value of attribute FILENAME where value of attribute SEQUENCE is equls to "1". Which would be the preferred way? SAX, DOM, XPath? and How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need:

```
  @Test
  public void test() throws Exception
  {
    String xml =
        "<FileIndex>\n" + 
        "<Document SEQUENCE=\"0\" FILENAME=\"A.xml\"  />\n" + 
        "<Document SEQUENCE=\"1\" FILENAME=\"B.htm\"  />\n" + 
        "<Document SEQUENCE=\"2\" FILENAME=\"C.htm\"  />\n" + 
        "<Document SEQUENCE=\"3\" FILENAME=\"D.htm\"  />\n" + 
        "</FileIndex>";
    XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    System.out.println(xp.evaluate("/FileIndex/Document[@SEQUENCE='1']/@FILENAME", new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)), XPathConstants.STRING));
  }
```

For such small XML it's best to use XPath

Comment: Thanks... It worked..
Even I was thinking of using XPath, bt was not aware how to write Exprssion for it.
Thanks..